# Converting CSV to KML using ruby_kml

Tags: csv, kml

I am having trouble with is creating a KML using ruby_kml from a CSV file so that I can utilize the addKML() or addKMLLayer() methods offered by gmaps4rails. I am having trouble getting the syntax to make sense. In api example it lists points explicitly like so
      ["$26A8",3023.1214,9744.5808],
      ["$26A9",3023.0842,9744.6805],
      ["$26AA",3022.9717,9744.5025],

my goal is to get it to read each row of the CSV and use that data for the kml. Here is my attempt at a solution.

```
def kml 
    require 'csv'
    require 'ruby_kml'
    curPoints = CSV.read('/postCSV/cur.csv'); # most recent upload
    kml = KMLFILE.new
    folder = KML::Folder.new(:name => 'ready')
    [
      **curPoints.each do |row|
        [row[0],row[1],row[3]]
      end** #data is in 0,1,3 
      # this shouldn't work because the loop isn't doing anything
      # I just don't see how to get it to match the example code     
        #for loop through row delimitating by name, lat, lng
    ].each do |name, lat, lng|
    folder.features << KML::Placemark.new(
      :name => name,
      :gemoetry => KML::Point.new(:coordinates => {:lat => lat, :lng => lng})
    )
    end
      kml.objects << folder
      @kml = kml.render
      return kml
    end
```

Comment: i'm still working on the problem on my own - one alternative i'm trying is:  curpoints.each do |row|
      kml.objects << Placemark.new(
        :name => row[0],
        :geometry => Point.new(:coordinates=> row[1],row[3])
    end
not sure if it will work yet

Comment: so i think that was closer to what i want but it kept giving me a " syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => :geometry => Point.new(:coordinates=>row[1],row[3]))" which didn't make sense - the error goes away when i hard code in a value like ' '-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0' - but that defeats the purpose...